# Phonegap barcode scanner plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have used BarcodeScanner v 1.1.0 plugin for my application but having problem scanning in some device and not scanning as fast as i need. can someone show me a better plugin that scans fast and also scans without the red-line so i can scan horizontally or vertically

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this from the GitHub. It's simple to integrate (add plugin), scans fast and is efficient.
https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner - the red line, am not sure how to remove it but it doesn't stop you scanning a barcode vertically or horizontally.

Comment: i am using phonegap build, can i integrate it?

Comment: @SamuelMoshie - I haven't tried that but logically, it should work.

Comment: i have switch to build localy bt having problem intergrating it. pls is there any tutorial on using this plugin online.???

Answer (score 0):

Manatee Works [Barcode Scanner SDK](https://manateeworks.com/barcode-scanner-sdk) plugin for PhoneGap can be found here:
https://github.com/manateeworks/phonegap-mwbarcodescanner

Together with useful info on how to add the Manatee Works Barcode Scanner SDK PhoneGap plugin to your project(s), how to build online with bulid.phonegap.com , scan an image, scan in partial screen view, important changes made by every release of the plugin, etc...

The plugin supports: Android, iOS and Windows. UPC and EAN are free. Other symbologies can be evaluated for free. More in-depth info can be found on the website at www.manateeworks.com or by contacting support at support@manateeworks.com

(Disclaimer: I'm member of Manateeworks support team.)